# Pagination and rewrite rules make problems in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, args

Wi have custom page on custom page template which should list user posts and this works but i have query arg that should filter between published and unpublished (draft) posts. On top of that well it should have pagination so it only shows 10 posts per page.

The problem exists when i want to list all posts and go to second page.

To be able to browse by filters and have pagination i had made custom rewrite and it works but without filters pagination only gives first page.

To better understand this is how it works.

`mywebsite.com/my-posts/` <---- this works

`mywebsite.com/my-posts/published/` <---- this works

`mywebsite.com/my-posts/published/page/2` <---- this works

`mywebsite.com/my-posts/page/2` <---- this DO NOT work

And without pretty permalinks structure is like this

`mywebsite.com/?page_id=23`

`mywebsite.com/?page_id=23&filter=published`

`mywebsite.com/?page_id=23&filter=published&paged=2`

`mywebsite.com/?page_id=23&paged=2`

Now if i do not use pretty permalinks it works but something i am missing with rewrite and i can't figure it out.

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%filter%', '([^&]+)');

    // add_rewrite_rule(get_post_field( 'post_name', get_theme_option('user_link') ) . '/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?','index.php?page_id='. get_theme_option('user_link') .'&user=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]','top');
    // add_rewrite_rule(get_post_field( 'post_name', get_theme_option('user_link') ) . '/([^/]+)/?','index.php?page_id='. get_theme_option('user_link') .'&user=$matches[1]','top');
    // add_rewrite_tag('%user%', '([^&]+)');

    add_rewrite_rule(get_post_field( 'post_name', get_theme_option('myprofile_page') ) . '/([^/]+)/?','index.php?page_id='. get_theme_option('myprofile_page') .'&filter=$matches[1]','top');
    add_rewrite_rule(get_post_field( 'post_name', get_theme_option('myprofile_page') ) . '/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?','index.php?page_id='. get_theme_option('myprofile_page') .'&filter=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]','bottom');
    add_rewrite_rule(get_post_field( 'post_name', get_theme_option('myprofile_page') ) . '/page/([0-9]{1,})/?','index.php?page_id='. get_theme_option('myprofile_page') .'&paged=$matches[1]','bottom');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);

function custom_query_vars( $vars ) {
    array_push($vars, 'filter');
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'custom_query_vars' );
```

I know this one `paged` with `filter` interferes with one another but this is the last solution i tried and it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Well to answer my own question if anyone else get stuck on something like this, it was really simple, i was missing only `$` at the end of regex to get it to work.

```
add_rewrite_rule( get_post_field( 'post_name', get_theme_option('myprofile_page') ) . '/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?page_id='. get_theme_option('myprofile_page') .'&filter=$matches[1]','top');
add_rewrite_rule( get_post_field( 'post_name', get_theme_option('myprofile_page') ) . '/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?page_id='. get_theme_option('myprofile_page') .'&filter=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]','top');
```